# Reading from a file into an array and storing the answer in another

Tags: c, arrays, file, loops

The below script is reading questions from a file and looping round and asking them to the user, i want the users answer to be stored in the array q.a and then at the end of the programme bot the questions ans the answers shown. All that happens at the minute is the last question asked and the last answer given is displayed 11 times. Can someone please help?

```
  struct qa{
  char q[40][250];
  char a[40][250];
  };

 int main()
 {
   int a, i, k, l, j;

   FILE *fp;
   fp = fopen("quest.txt", "r");
   if (fp == NULL){
        printf("nope nothing in there\n");
   }

   struct qa q;

      for(i>0;i<=11;i++){
      fgets(q.q[l], 250, (FILE*)fp);
      printf("%s", q.q[l]);
      scanf("%s", q.a[l]);
      }

      for (i = 0; i < 11; i++){    
        printf("%s\n %s\n", q.a[l], q.q[l]);
      }
}
```

Comment: `for(i>0;i<=11;i++){`  --> `for (i = 0; i <= 11; i++){` Also, `l` is not initialized. You probably want to use `i` and not `l`.

Comment: Ive made these changes and it does the same thing

Comment: If you print the index (`l`, but I am with Johnny, you probably want `i`)  along with the Q&A, what does it say?

Comment: Could you upgrade to a [mcve]? Some of the possible errors do not survive making one.